# How to replace a rgb value with hex value in string using regular expression

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a regular expression by which i can replace rgb color value with hex code in a string. The string may have following types :

```
=> rgb(0, 0, 0) 0 0 0
=> rgb(0 100, 200)
=> 0 0 rgb(201,45,65)
```

First i want to access the rgb value from the string and then replace it back with hex code. So result will be :

```
=> #XXXXXX 0 0 0 
=> #XXXXXX
=> 0 0 #XXXXXX
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var newstr = Regex.Replace(
                input, 
                @"rgb\([ ]*(\d+)[ ]*,[ ]*(\d+)[ ]*,[ ]*(\d+)[ ]*\)", 
                m => {
                    return "#" + Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value).ToString("X2") +
                    Int32.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value).ToString("X2") +
                    Int32.Parse(m.Groups[3].Value).ToString("X2");
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the values from your string, you could do a substring based on index of `"rbg("` and `")"` and then do subsequent splits on `" "` and/or `","`. Then...

See here:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/268611-convert-rgb-hexadecimal

```
public static string ToHtml ( System.Drawing.Color color )
{
   if (System.Drawing.Color.Transparent == color)
      return "Transparent";
   return string.Concat("#", (color.ToArgb() & 0x00FFFFFF).ToString("X6"));
}
```

Or:

```
System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(longRgb);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
string str = "rgb(0 100, 200)";

int startindex = str.IndexOf("rgb(");

int endindex = str.LastIndexOf(')');

string result = str.Substring(0, startindex) 
              + "#XXXXXX" 
              + str.Substring(endindex + 1);
```

Tried for all 3 options you have given.